# Sharing objects between users with Backand

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, backand

Im using [Backand](https://www.backand.com) BaaS, with my Ionic application. I want to implement functionality to share objects between users. Preferably also include ways to set permissions on said objects.

Any references or guides to this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add permission to objects, you can use predefined filters.
They check data on user and based on this data allow or disallow the user to fetch or change the objects.

More information can be found in [Backand](https://www.backand.com) documentation, [here](http://docs.backand.com/en/latest/what_would_you_like_to_do/retrieve_data/) and [here](http://docs.backand.com/en/latest/what_would_you_like_to_do/security/).

[image]